# How to write rspec test case to test successful execution of a method and exception condition also?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I want to write an rspec unit test case, so that if internet connection exists it will connect to gmail, else it will raise exception.

I have tried to write something, but it server **only one part of the problem**. 
How could I write a unit test case so that it can test both, ie. will assert exception if unable to connect gmail else will test successful connection.

```
describe "#will create an authenticated gmail session" do
    it "should connect to gmail, if internet connection exists else raise exception" do
       @mail_sender = MailSender.new
       lambda { @mail_sender.connect_to_gmail}.should raise_error
    end
end
```

Method definition

```
def connect_to_gmail
    begin
      gmail = Gmail.new('abc@gmail.com', 'Password123' )
    rescue SocketError=>se
       raise "Unable to connect gmail #{se}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [stubs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-4/docs/method-stubs) or [should_receive](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-5/docs/message-expectations) here.

**case 1** (the behavior when internet connection exists):

```
it "should connect to gmail, if internet connection exists" do
  Gmail.should_receive(:new)
  @mail_sender = MailSender.new
  -> { @mail_sender.connect_to_gmail}.should_not raise_error
end
```

maybe you would like to return some object (`Gmail.should_receive(:new).and_return(some_object)`) and continue to work with this stubbed object

**case 2** (the behavior when internet connection does not exist):

```
it "should raise error to gmail, if internet connection does not exist" do
  Gmail.stub(:new) { raise SocketError }
  @mail_sender = MailSender.new
  -> { @mail_sender.connect_to_gmail}.should raise_error
end
```

I hope this code helps you